# Query does not work with Mysqli php class but works in MySQL workbench

Tags: php, php-mysqlidb

I am using the mysqli db class found at [github](https://github.com/ajillion/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class/blob/master/MysqliDb.php)

my query looks like

```
$db->query('
  SELECT
    memberID,zoneCode,state,zone,countyName,
    CONCAT(state,\'Z\',zone) as fullZoneCode
  FROM members_zonesToWatch
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT state,zone,countyName
    FROM countyPublicForcastZoneCorrelation
  ) as zones
    ON zoneCode = CONCAT(state,\'Z\',zone)');
```

The issue im getting is

```
Fatal error: Problem preparing query 
(SELECT
  memberID,zoneCode,state,zone,countyName,
   CONCAT(state,'Z',zone) as fullZoneCode
 FROM members_zonesToWatch
 LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT state,zone,countyName
   FROM countyPublicForcastZoneCorrelation
 ) as zones
   ON zoneCode = CONCAT(state,'Z',zone)) 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
''Z',zone) as fullZoneCode FROM members_zonesToWatch LEFT' at line 1
```

This query as it is works in mysql workbench just fine.  What is wrong with it using the mysqli class?

Comment: Hi, I inserted some newlines to the query and the error message for readability.

Comment: Try to use `"` instead of `\'`. I know it's not different. But just try maybe works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing on your case, the problem is the `'Z'` and `$db->query`

It is because the `MysqliDB` internally uses `mysqli` and `mysqli` throws the exception when `prepare` your statement (from the debugger, it seems the quote `'` turns to `&#39;`).

Instead, `MysqliDB` provide `rawQuery` for cases like yours. So use the below :

```
$result = $db->rawQuery('
    SELECT m.memberID, CONCAT(m.state, ? ,m.zone) as fullZoneCode
    FROM members_zonesToWatch m
    LEFT JOIN countyPublicForcastZoneCorrelation c
    ON c.zoneCode = CONCAT(m.state, ? ,m.zone)',
    array('Z','Z'));
```

Reference: [PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class / MysqliDb.php](https://github.com/ajillion/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class/blob/master/MysqliDb.php);

Comment: @bretterer the second parameter of rawQuery is simply an array of all used parameters

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't that be

```
SELECT
m.memberID, m.zoneCode, m.state, m.zone, m.countyName,
CONCAT(m.state,'Z',m.zone) as fullZoneCode,
c.state, c.zone, c.countyName
FROM members_zonesToWatch m
LEFT JOIN countyPublicForcastZoneCorrelation c
ON c.zoneCode = CONCAT(m.state, 'Z', m.zone)
```

Comment: That gives me `Fatal error: Problem preparing query 
(SELECT m.memberID, m.zoneCode, m.state, m.zone, m.countyName, CONCAT(m.state,'Z',m.zone) as fullZoneCode, c.state, c.zone, c.countyName FROM members_zonesToWatch m LEFT JOIN countyPublicForcastZoneCorrelation c ON c.zoneCode = CONCAT(m.state, 'Z', m.zone)) 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Z',m.zone) as fullZoneCode, c.state, c.zone, c.countyName FROM members_' at line 3` and now does not work in mysql workbench.  Says unknown col m.state

Comment: It seems then that you can't use CONCAT as one of the parameters of the ON statement

Comment: Is that a limitation of the class or mysqli?  This works just fine with my old MySQL class.

Comment: @bretterer: "Unknown col m.state"? Is there a field 'state' in the table 'members_zonestowatch'? I would start anew with a query having one field and one table; add the necessary fields from that table until everything is ok, then add the second query in the same manner.

Comment: @Noam-newman:  That was it... it should be just c.state, c.zone,c.countyName and the concat's should be c's as well... Thanks!  HOWEVER, it still does not work within the mysqli class.  I still get the same error

Comment: @bretterer: Post the query as it stands now and the error message. I don't know anything about mysqli classes but I know SQL. Try putting in the mysqli class a simple query and build that up until the query works.